# JSON Serialize array returns NULL in JSON string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am building a JSON model like this

```
JObject issue_model = JObject.FromObject(new
{
   labels = new[] { "import", "automation"}
}
```

below code for serialization

```
string request_json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(issue_model,
                  Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                  new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore });
```

But when i try to build this from a dynamic list of values like

```
   list<string> lp_list = new list<string>();
   //lp_list contains a list of string values
   string[] lp_labels = lp_list.ToArray();
   JObject issue_model = JObject.FromObject(new
   {
      labels = jira_labels
   }
```

I got the JSON as

```
   "labels": [
  [
    null,
    null
  ]
]
```

But i am expecting this json as

> "labels" : { "import", "automation"}

How can i make the array serialization right way

Comment: you migth want to first build a model class to represent your json object in c#. This way you can define a property of name labels and save a `List<string>` or a `string[]` in there. Have a look at [this quicktype example](https://app.quicktype.io?share=A77T9m7kz1mv6PXzgQ9F)  i through together

Comment: I have some restrictions of using model class approach . since i have lot of properties and it is  varying for each request. So i prefer on the go or t dynamic model creation

Comment: What is `jira_labels`?

Comment: Am I guessing right that you want to have `lp_list` inside the labels property at the end? If yes why are your asigning `jira_labels` to it?

Answer (score 4):

I modified your code in a console Application.

```
List<string> lp_list = new List<string>();
lp_list.Add("import");
lp_list.Add("automation");

//lp_list contains a list of string values
//string[] lp_labels = lp_list.ToArray();
JObject issue_model = JObject.FromObject(new
{
    labels = lp_list
});

Console.WriteLine(issue_model);
```

The result is as follows:
[image]

Hope it answers your question.

Comment: The `lp_list.ToArray()` isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Yeah,I modify code like this " labels = lp_list"，it also take effective.

Comment: Thanks oh and +1 for finishing basically 2 seconds before me with the answer

Comment: my pleasure :).

Comment: This is the code i used and its my mistake of assigning items to list string . Now i figured it out an thanks for the help